# Python stops at a print statement

Tags: python

```
while Winner == "":
    while First_Player_Turn == "Y":
        while rtd != "":
            try:
                rtd = input("{} press enter to roll the dice".format(First_Player))
                if rtd == "":
                    dice = random.randint(1, 6)
                    First_Player_Position = dice + First_Player_Position
                    steps_left = 50 - First_Player_Position
                    print("{} needs {} steps to finish".format(First_Player, steps_left))
                    if First_Player_Position >= 50:
                        Winner = "Y"
                    First_Player_Turn = "N"
                    Second_Player_Turn = "Y"
                    print("Test to see if this is printed - It is but not in wingide")
                    continue
             except:
                    print("Please press enter")                    
    while Second_Player_Turn == "Y":
```

I have tested this multiple times and I have found out that wingide doesn't show the Tested part but normal Python does. What I want to happen is when it has run through the `First_Player_Turn` loop to go to the `Second_Player_Turn` loop.

Comment: We are not here to fix your work for you, we will help.  What have you tried?

Comment: If you are getting different results from the command-line and an IDE, the most common issue is that you are running two different versions of python, maybe 2 and 3.  `input()` in particular can send you down strange routes.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question in its current state. It would help if you post a [mcve] that others can use to try & reproduce your problem. BTW, it's not recommended to use unnamed `except` like that, and it's not clear why you have it in your code. What do you expect it do?

Answer (score 0):

You do not show the initialisation of the string variables. Your program starts with the following:

```
while Winner == "":
    while First_Player_Turn == "Y":
        while rtd != "":
```

- If `Winner` is initialised as `""`, the outer loop will run.
- If `First_Player_Turn` is initialised as `"Y"`, the middle loop will run.
- If `rtd` is *not* initialised as `""`, the inner loop will run.

Because you haven't shown the initialisation of **all** three variables, you're obviously relying on magic for them to start with exactly the right values. Because that is unlikely, odds on *none* of the loops will run.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out myself, the rtd was conflicting with other rtd's sorry for wasting your time.